# Converting a mono audio strip to a stereo audio strip

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have imported an mp4 video file (an interview) into the VSE, for use with an animation. The audio of the video file is mono. I want the VSE to output a video file with the audio in stereo (so that the video is played on two speakers, not one, as is the case now). How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

In the Sidebar check mono.
Duplicate the audio Shift + D to a new channel.
In the Sidebar set Pan value to -1 in one audio strip and +1 in the other.

[image]